# Why successfull DBCC CHECKIDENT throws SqlException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have this code inside my stored procedure

```
if exists (select * from import.table)
begin
    delete import.table

    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('import.table', RESEED, 0);
end
```

In C# I call an Entity Framework function, which calls the database procedure

```
try {
    database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec usp_storedProcedureName");
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    // error here
}
```

And I am getting this message:

> Checking identity information: current identity value '\', current column value '\'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator

Any idea why? Can it be caused by some transaction mismatch?

Comment: Looks like a minor bug -- this message ought to be processed as informational. Even if there is another error, this one should not be rolled into it. Either use `DBCC CHECKIDENT ... WITH NO_INFOMSGS` to suppress this message (which is a good idea to do in a stored procedure anyway) or just use `TRUNCATE TABLE import.table`, which will reset the identity without the need for `CHECKIDENT` in the first place (and produces less transaction logging than `DELETE` as a bonus).

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert's assessment that it's an issue with the way informational and error messages are handled. I'm surprised to see '\' in the message since SQL Server returns integers for those values in the message text, There might be more going on here.

Comment: My apology, i mistakenly thought that exception is thrown by DBCC because that DBCC message was included in the error message but the exception is thrown by transaction mismatch. The '\' is my copy paste mistake, in original message there are numbers.